Splitting rows into multiple rows based on stock quantities using SQL
I have below 2 tables as input:
Table 1: Buy



Buy_Date
Buy_Time_in_hundred_hours
Buy_Qty
Buy_Per_Share
Buy_Total_Value




15-May
10
10
10
100


15-May
14
20
10
200


15-May
15
10
10
100



Table 2: Sell



Sell_Date
Sell_Time_in_hundred_hours
Sell_Qty
Sell_Per_Share
Sell_Total_Value




15-May
15
35
20
700



I want this output:



Date
Buy_Time
Buy_Qty
Buy_Per_Share_Price
Buy_Total_Value
Sell_Qty
Sell_Per_Share_Price
Sell_Total_Value




15
10
10
10
100
10
20
200


15
14
20
10
200
20
20
400


15
15
5
10
50
5
20
100


15
15
5
10
50






Explanation
Say suppose by end of day we sold 35 quantities of the share (out of 40 quantities that we purchased). So, 1st row contains 10 sell quantities (from total of 35 quantities that we sold) in order to nullify the purchase of first 10 stocks. Similarly, 2nd row contains 20 sell quantities in order to nullify the purchase of 20 stocks. Lastly, we have 5 quantities left and hence the buy quantities are split into 2 rows.
I tried exploring solution using below sql but still I am unable to get proper output. Seems like I am missing on some basic stuff. Can someone pls help with the problem?
SELECT 
    b.buy_Date,
    b.buy_Time_in_hundred_hours AS Buy_Time,
    LEAST(b.Qty, s.Qty) AS Buy_Qty,
    b.Per_Share_Price AS Buy_Per_Share_Price,
    LEAST(b.Qty, s.Qty) * b.Per_Share_Price AS Buy_Total_Value,
    GREATEST(0, s.Qty - LEAST(b.Qty, s.Qty)) AS Sell_Qty,
    s.Per_Share_Price AS Sell_Per_Share_Price,
    GREATEST(0, s.Qty - LEAST(b.Qty, s.Qty)) * s.Per_Share_Price AS Sell_Total_Value
FROM 
    BUY b
LEFT JOIN 
    SELL s ON b.buy_Date = s.sell_Date 
ORDER BY 
    b.buy_Date, b.buy_Time_in_hundred_hours;


As there is no way of telling which exact bought shares should be mapped to which sold shares (because you only have a date), there is no query that will have a deterministic output for any given day. Is it an option to group all orders per day? That will give you consistent output at least.

@MartinSchapendonk There is a column for time as well as date.

Mea culpa, missed that on first read.

Don't have time to work this out now but I would go for a solution with a UNION ALL  of buy and sell tables, multiply all sell values by -1, order total result set by date/time and then use lag/lead analytical functions to calculate the running total. Hope this helps.

If I got it right, you should create a cte with "transactions" of selling purchased quantities and split the remaining quantity to a row showing the selling transaction and additional row showing the remaining (not sold) purchased qty.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    buy (BUY_DATE, BUY_TIME, BUY_QTY, BUY_PER_SHARE, BUY_TOTAL_VAL) AS
        ( Select DATE '2024-05-15', 10, 10, 10, 100 From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-05-15', 14, 20, 10, 200 From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-05-15', 15, 10, 10, 100 From Dual 
        ), 
    sell (SELL_DATE, SELL_TIME, SELL_QTY, SELL_PER_SHARE, SELL_TOTAL_VAL) AS 
        ( Select DATE '2024-05-15', 15, 35, 20, 700 From Dual 
        ),

Create transactions CTE (named it grid) that uses Sum() Over() analytic functions to calculate values out of running sums (windowing claause - Rows Between). Last row have different status (Balance) to be used in main SQL to split the qty in two rows using Union...
--  transaction calculations using running sums
  grid AS
    ( Select  b.BUY_DATE, b.BUY_TIME, b.BUY_QTY, b.BUY_PER_SHARE, b.BUY_TOTAL_VAL, 
              --
              Case When Nvl(s.SELL_QTY, 0) >= Sum(b.BUY_QTY) Over( Order By s.FROM_DATE, b.BUY_TIME Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
                   Then b.BUY_QTY 
              Else Sum(b.BUY_QTY) Over( Order By s.FROM_DATE, b.BUY_TIME Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) - s.SELL_QTY
              End "SELL_QTY", 
              --
              s.SELL_PER_SHARE, 
              --
              Case When Nvl(s.SELL_QTY, 0) >= Sum(b.BUY_QTY) Over( Order By s.FROM_DATE, b.BUY_TIME Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
                   Then b.BUY_QTY 
              Else Sum(b.BUY_QTY) Over( Order By s.FROM_DATE, b.BUY_TIME Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) - s.SELL_QTY
              End * s.SELL_PER_SHARE "SELL_TOTAL_VAL",
              --
              Case When Nvl(s.SELL_QTY, 0) >= Sum(b.BUY_QTY) Over( Order By s.FROM_DATE, b.BUY_TIME Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
                   Then 'TRADE' 
              Else Case When s.FROM_DATE Is Not Null Then 'BALANCE' Else 'NO_TRANSACTIONS' End 
              End "STATUS"
      From        buy b
      Left  Join  ( Select    Min(SELL_DATE) "FROM_DATE", Max(SELL_DATE) "TILL_DATE",
                              SELL_PER_SHARE, Sum(SELL_QTY) "SELL_QTY", Sum(SELL_TOTAL_VAL) "SELL_TOTAL_VAL"
                    From      sell
                    Group By  SELL_PER_SHARE
                  )s ON( s.FROM_DATE >= b.BUY_DATE )
    ) 

--      M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT      g.BUY_DATE, g.BUY_TIME, 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) Else g.BUY_QTY End "BUY_QTY",
            g.BUY_PER_SHARE, 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) Else g.BUY_QTY End * g.BUY_PER_SHARE "BUY_TOTAL_VAL", 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) Else g.SELL_QTY End "SELL_QTY", 
            g.SELL_PER_SHARE, 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) * g.SELL_PER_SHARE Else g.SELL_TOTAL_VAL End "SELL_TOTAL_VAL"
FROM        grid g
UNION ALL
SELECT      g.BUY_DATE, g.BUY_TIME, 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then g.BUY_QTY - (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) Else g.BUY_QTY End "BUY_QTY",
            g.BUY_PER_SHARE, 
            Case When g.STATUS = 'BALANCE' Then g.BUY_QTY - (g.BUY_QTY - g.SELL_QTY) Else g.BUY_QTY End * g.BUY_PER_SHARE "BUY_TOTAL_VAL", 
            Null, Null, Null
FROM        grid g
WHERE       g.STATUS = 'BALANCE'
ORDER BY    BUY_DATE, BUY_TIME, SELL_TOTAL_VAL

/*    R e s u l t :
BUY_DATE   BUY_TIME    BUY_QTY BUY_PER_SHARE BUY_TOTAL_VAL   SELL_QTY SELL_PER_SHARE SELL_TOTAL_VAL
-------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ------------- ---------- -------------- --------------
15.05.24         10         10            10           100         10             20            200
15.05.24         14         20            10           200         20             20            400
15.05.24         15          5            10            50          5             20            100
15.05.24         15          5            10            50                                             */

NOTE:
If there were different selling prices involved then this should be adjusted either by using average price or in some other way. It is a question which price should be used first and what to do with the case when one purchased qty is sold in two (or more) steps with two (or more) different prices. What if there is purchased qty = 3 and it was sold 1 by 1, each with different selling price?!
With one selling price this will work on different dates too - see it bellow:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    buy (BUY_DATE, BUY_TIME, BUY_QTY, BUY_PER_SHARE, BUY_TOTAL_VAL) AS
        ( Select DATE '2024-05-13', 10, 10, 10, 100 From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-05-14', 14, 20, 10, 200 From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-05-15', 15, 10, 10, 100 From Dual 
        ), 
    sell (SELL_DATE, SELL_TIME, SELL_QTY, SELL_PER_SHARE, SELL_TOTAL_VAL) AS 
        ( Select DATE '2024-05-16', 15, 31, 20, 620 From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2024-05-17', 15,  4, 20,  80 From Dual
        ),

... using same query as above ...
/*    R e s u l t :
BUY_DATE   BUY_TIME    BUY_QTY BUY_PER_SHARE BUY_TOTAL_VAL   SELL_QTY SELL_PER_SHARE SELL_TOTAL_VAL
-------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ------------- ---------- -------------- --------------
13.05.24         10         10            10           100         10             20            200
14.05.24         14         20            10           200         20             20            400
15.05.24         15          5            10            50          5             20            100
15.05.24         15          5            10            50                                             */


You can use ROLLUP to generate an extra row for each of the buy and sell tables and calculate the cumulative total of buys and sells and then FULL OUTER JOIN the tables based on those cumulative totals:
WITH buys_with_total (
  buy_date, buy_time, buy_qty, buy_per_share, total_prev_qty, total_qty
) AS (
  SELECT buy_date,
         MAX(buy_time),
         CASE GROUPING_ID(buy_time, buy_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(buy_qty) END,
         CASE GROUPING_ID(buy_time, buy_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(buy_per_share) END,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(
             CASE GROUPING_ID(buy_time, buy_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(buy_qty) END
           ) OVER (
              PARTITION BY buy_date
              ORDER BY buy_time, buy_per_share
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ),
           0
         ),
         CASE GROUPING_ID(buy_time, buy_per_share)
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUM(
                SUM(buy_qty)
              ) OVER (PARTITION BY buy_date ORDER BY buy_time, buy_per_share)
         END
  FROM   buy
  GROUP BY buy_date, ROLLUP((buy_time, buy_per_share))
),
sells_with_total (
  sell_date, sell_time, sell_qty, sell_per_share, total_prev_qty, total_qty
) AS (
  SELECT sell_date,
         MAX(sell_time),
         CASE GROUPING_ID(sell_time, sell_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(sell_qty) END,
         CASE GROUPING_ID(sell_time, sell_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(sell_per_share) END,
         COALESCE(
           SUM(
             CASE GROUPING_ID(sell_time, sell_per_share) WHEN 0 THEN SUM(sell_qty) END
           ) OVER (
              PARTITION BY sell_date
              ORDER BY sell_time, sell_per_share
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ),
           0
         ),
         CASE GROUPING_ID(sell_time, sell_per_share)
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUM(
                SUM(sell_qty)
              ) OVER (PARTITION BY sell_date ORDER BY sell_time, sell_per_share)
         END
  FROM   sell s
  GROUP BY sell_date, ROLLUP((sell_time, sell_per_share))
)
SELECT COALESCE(b.buy_date, s.sell_date) AS dt,
       b.buy_time,
       LEAST(b.total_qty, COALESCE(s.total_qty, b.total_qty))
         - GREATEST(b.total_prev_qty, COALESCE(s.total_prev_qty, b.total_prev_qty))
         AS buy_qty,
       b.buy_per_share,
       (
         LEAST(b.total_qty, COALESCE(s.total_qty, b.total_qty))
         - GREATEST(b.total_prev_qty, COALESCE(s.total_prev_qty, b.total_prev_qty))
       ) * b.buy_per_share AS buy_total_value,
       s.sell_time,
       (
         LEAST(s.total_qty, COALESCE(b.total_qty, s.total_qty))
         - GREATEST(s.total_prev_qty, COALESCE(b.total_prev_qty, s.total_prev_qty))
       ) AS sell_qty,
       s.sell_per_share,
       (
         LEAST(s.total_qty, COALESCE(b.total_qty, s.total_qty))
         - GREATEST(s.total_prev_qty, COALESCE(b.total_prev_qty, s.total_prev_qty))
       ) * s.sell_per_share AS sell_total_value
FROM   buys_with_total b
       FULL OUTER JOIN sells_with_total s
       ON (
             s.sell_date = b.buy_date
         AND (s.total_prev_qty < b.total_qty OR b.total_qty IS NULL)
         AND (b.total_prev_qty < s.total_qty OR s.total_qty IS NULL)
       )
WHERE  NOT (b.total_qty IS NULL AND s.total_qty IS NULL)

Which, for an expanded set of sample data:
CREATE TABLE buy (BUY_DATE, BUY_TIME, BUY_QTY, BUY_PER_SHARE) AS
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 10,  5, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 11,  5,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-15', 10, 10, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-15', 14, 20, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-15', 15, 10, 10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE sell (SELL_DATE, SELL_TIME, SELL_QTY, SELL_PER_SHARE) AS
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 10,  2, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 11,  7, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-14', 12,  5, 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-05-15', 15, 35, 20 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DT
BUY_TIME
BUY_QTY
BUY_PER_SHARE
BUY_TOTAL_VALUE
SELL_TIME
SELL_QTY
SELL_PER_SHARE
SELL_TOTAL_VALUE




2024-05-14 00:00:00
10
2
10
20
10
2
20
40


2024-05-14 00:00:00
10
3
10
30
11
3
15
45


2024-05-14 00:00:00
11
4
5
20
11
4
15
60


2024-05-14 00:00:00
11
1
5
5
12
1
25
25


2024-05-14 00:00:00
11
null
null
null
12
4
25
100


2024-05-15 00:00:00
10
10
10
100
15
10
20
200


2024-05-15 00:00:00
14
20
10
200
15
20
20
400


2024-05-15 00:00:00
15
5
10
50
15
5
20
100


2024-05-15 00:00:00
15
5
10
50
15
null
null
null



fiddle
